# How to introduce a python int in a server answer HTTP

Tags: python, html, http

I've to create a HTTP Server that answers me with a link to my page. This link have to be different when I do a HTTP request, so I am using random.randint(a,b) for generate a random int, but I don't know how to integrate it in HTML. Slice of my code..

```
        recvSocket.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" +
                    "<html>" +
                    "<head><title>Random URL - SAT - David Manso dmanso</title></head>" +
                    "<body>" +
                    "<h1>Hola.</h1>" +
                    "<h4>Dame otra</h4>" +
                    random.randint(123456789,987654321) +
                    "</body></html>" +
                    "\r\n")
    recvSocket.close()
```

Comment: "Creating a HTTP server that answers a random link" seems way too broad. [Picking a web framework](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks/), reading the documentation and getting acquainted with it, will help you ask a more specific question

Comment: Also, your code indicates you're trying to reimplement HTTP at the socket level, while there are excellent libraries fulfilling that requirement. Unless you're trying to learn HTTP (as opposed to creating a site), try not to reinvent the wheel - it leads to wasted effort and, generally speaking, very poor results in practice